# The same REST service, different behavior for different virtual directories. 404 error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest

1- I have a piece of code that is deployed on the server. This code calls for a REST service.

2- The same physical server, where the code is, is being pointed at by multiple virtual directories, each virtual folder has a different name.

3- For the first virtual directory, everything is working fine and the code calls the REST service.

4- For the second virtual directory, which points to the same exact code, and points to the same physical folder (not even a copy of the code) can't find the REST service, it gives 404.

Any idea what could be happening? I am not sure if this is enough information or not, I would be glad to provide more.

The URL is constructed dynamically this way

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("rest/AuthenticationAttempt", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(AuthenticationService)));
```

In the web.config, I have this

```
 <location path="rest">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The service URL is

`http://10.30.10.172/OnlineServicing/rest/AuthenticationAttempt/`

OnlineServicing is the virtual directory name, AuthenticationAttempt is the service name. However, the deployed code doesn't have a rest folder, it looks like the code handles this.

Comment: What does the code look like that calls the service?  Most likely, you are not using absolute URLs.  Both the web.config and calling code will be useful to see.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: Yes, the URL is constructed dynamically. It is IIS 6.
Is there something specific you want to see in the web.config, the same web.config is used of the 2 virtual directories, since they are pointing to the same physical folder.

Comment: Are you sure the second virtual directory is correctly setup? You've not got a typo or anything... That is what I would think most likely to cause a 404...